# Spring Data mongo template return an array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

This is my MongoDB query https://mongoplayground.net/p/QsqE15TlD3t ; In short, I do a match, group and accumulate as an array and project. I am trying to do that in Spring MongoDB like

```
Criteria c1 = Criteria.where("geoNameId").in(geoIdList);

    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            match(c1),
            group( "_id").
            push("network").as("network"),
            project("network"));
    AggregationResults<TestModel> groupResults
            = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, IPv4AddressesDocument.class, TestModel.class);
    List<TestModel> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

TestModel

```
public class TestModel {
List<String> network;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestModel{" +
            "network=" + network +
            '}';
}
```

}

But what I get is the return of List of TestModel objects and each object is a list of Strings. What I need is to get a list of strings as output. Any help appreciated. !

Comment: Your linked mongoplayground query has `$group: { _id: "$id",` - I believe it is not correct, as the input document doen't have the `id` field.  So, the present result is as expected.

Comment: ok. I am a beginner with MongoDB query. My objective here is to get all documents in a collection that matches a criteria and extract a field in the collection and return that specific field as an array. any pointers on how to do that ?

Comment: You can update your question with a sample expected result (for a sample input documents).